# Merging CSV files to a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

I want to merge several CSV files to a dataframe.
With the code below it does what I want but only the last file is merged. How can I change the code so all files are merged?

```
V_timeSeries = pd.read_csv('timeSeries.csv')

#merge each file with time series on centiseconds
raw_files=['labelled_raw1.csv','labelled_raw2.csv','labelled_raw3.csv','labelled_raw4.csv','labelled_raw5.csv','labelled_raw6.csv' ]
first=True
for file in raw_files:
    V_raw=pd.read_csv(file)
    V_walk = V_raw.merge(V_timeSeries, on='centiseconds', how='outer') 
V_walk = V_walk.fillna(method='ffill') #where the dataframes have been merged, many rows will have NA, so the value is taken from the previous filled row and copied down. Now each centisecond is labelled with an activyt rather than only once ever 3000 centisecond.
V_walk = V_walk.loc[(V_walk['walking'] == 1) & (V_walk['imputed'] == 0) & (V_walk['moderate'] == 0) & (V_walk['sedentary'] == 0) & (V_walk['sleep'] == 0) & (V_walk['tasks-light'] == 0)]
V_walk = V_walk.drop(['acceleration', 'imputed', 'moderate', 'sedentary', 'sleep', 'tasks-light','MET'], axis=1)
print("walking_identified")
```

Answer (score 0):

You keep rewriting V_walk, so only the last file append gets stored.

```
for file in raw_files: 
    V_raw=pd.read_csv(file)
    V_timeSeries = V_timeSeries.merge(V_raw, on = 'centiseconds', how = 
                   'outer')
 V_walk = V_timeSeries #if you want to use V_walk as the new name
```